# problem when download a image from website using beautiful soap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am wrtiting this code to get information about top movies and also download the image blong to the movie but on some image they downloaded but their size are 0 but they have size on disk when i kilick on the link of the image that i cant download it well its opening well and there is no problem in link
for exampele this is one of the link that images :
https://static.stacker.com/s3fs-public/styles/slide_desktop/s3/00000116_4_0.png

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


URL = "https://stacker.com/stories/1587/100-best-movies-all-time"
count = 0
local_description = ""
movie_data = []
data = requests.get(URL).text
soap = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
titles = soap.find_all(name="h2", class_="ct-slideshow__slide__text-container__caption")[1:]
description = soap.find_all(name="div", class_="ct-slideshow__slide__text-container__description")[1:]
images = soap.find_all(name="img", typeof="foaf:Image")[6:106]

for num in range(100):
    movie_name = titles[num].getText().replace("\n", "")
    local_des = description[num].find_all(name="p")[1:]
    for s in local_des:
        local_description = s.getText().replace(" ", "")
    local_data = {"title": movie_name, "description": local_description}
    movie_data.append(local_data)
    movie_image_link = images[num].get("src")
    response = requests.get(movie_image_link)
    with open(f"images/{movie_name}.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    count += 1
    print(count)

data_collected = pd.DataFrame(movie_data)
data_collected.to_csv("Data/100_movie.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my problem in some movie name there was ":" and as you knwo you cant user ":"
in file names i fix the code with .replace()

```
movie_name.replace(":", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a response, check if it's empty before writing to disk. Might need to retry or the link may be bad.

Comment: if response.content != "":

        with open(f"images/{movie_name}.png", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
    else:
        print(movie_name) still have the problem